# ATtiny/ATmega programmer board - need a 6 x 1:3 Mux solution

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, multiplexer

Hey so I'm trying to create a circuit on perf board that allows me to program three different types of chips using an Arduino Duemilanove as ISP.  Those chips are the ATtiny85, ATtiny84, and ATMega328.

I want to use one 28-pin ZIF socket for all 3 chips, and not have to remember a specific placement for the chip, so I just want each chip to sit at the very top of the ZIF socket for the 8-pin 85 and 14-pin 84.

So I've mapped out all the connections that will need to go into the ZIF socket, and now have come across a switching problem.

Essentially there will be 3 states, one for each type of chip, and there are 6 signals that need to be switched (5V, GND, RST, MOSI, MISO, and SCK).

I've mapped out which pins each signal will need to go to, but now I need an analog switch IC or analog multiplexer to make this happen.

For example, MOSI looks like this:

State 1: MOSI -> 25
State 2: MOSI -> 7
State 3: MOSI -> 17

Since I have 6 signals, and 3 states, ideally a 6 channel 1:3 Demux would be perfect, but I think it's pretty certain those don't exist. It seems like the most practical I can find so far is a dual channel 1:4 demux, so I would need to use 3 of those.

Essentially what I'm here for is 1) Does anybody know of a better way to do this, or 2) Does anybody know of any IC's that can solve this?

Comment: Why not just connect all potential pins, and Hi-Z the ones you don't need to use?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Do you mean Hi-Z the pins on the chip being programmed? I thought that required programming the chip...I'm a little confused by how that would work.  And some of the pins overlap, for instance pin 7 goes to MOSI with the 84, and 5V with the 328

Comment: Hi-Z the pins on the device doing the programming, so that they don't affect the device being programmed. Overlap between signal and power can be handled by using a transistor with a pullup/pulldown.

Comment: [Related reading.](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc1108.pdf)

Comment: Okay but each pin on the board doing the programming stays consistent.  So pin 10 for instance is the RST connection for all 3 chips. 
http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Tutorial/SimpleBreadboardAVR.png

and http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-3RpB2COVHjI/TkBXUdm-i1I/AAAAAAAAACU/THx73jgf1bY/s1600/fritzing.png

Comment: Which is why you read the related reading that I linked.

Comment: I agree with @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams In other words, solve this problem in software, the Arduino sketch for programming AVRs is fully open source and although not very well commented, it shouldn't be too hard to follow with Google around.

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to what that does and how it solves the problem. How does that allow me to switch between say Vcc and RST on pin 1, or MOSI and Vcc on pin 7?

Comment: Maybe I worded it confusingly. Are you thinking I mean pins on the arduino? When I say pin 7 I mean pin 7 of the ZIF socket, not the programmer.

Comment: You use "virtual" SPI connections, and route them to the appropriate Arduino pins. The Arduino pin connected to pin 1 on the socket can either be the virtual RST, or it can be held high to provide Vcc. Same with pin 1 on the socket and the virtual MOSI.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So I can effectively just change which pins the signals come through on the Arduino? And so that means I would need to hardwire to each potential pin on the ZIF socket that might need a signal? There are 14 potential pins. This sounds amazing if I could make it work without having to do any switching at all.  And just one more concern, how good of a ground is a digital out written as LOW? I've heard from some saying it's a very bad one..

Comment: You probably want to put a 74AC driver between the Arduino pins and the device, in order to provide a decent supply and ground.

Comment: Would actual 5V Vcc be hooked into the input of a buffer, and actual GND hooked to the output of a buffer, and then just control them with more digital pins? So I would need 3 additional digital pins to control buffers for Vcc/GND for each type of chip?

Comment: Sorry for the multitude of questions! I'm partially mentally retarded. I just realized I don't need to switch any signals below pin 7 on the left and 22 on the right since the only chip that will reach that far is the 328, doh

Comment: For Vcc and GND you can just pin the MCU outputs to high or low, and let the 74AC supply them.

Comment: Well appreciate the help, but I've gotta be honest though. That software SPI datasheet is so lacking and information on the web seems so sparse that perhaps it'd just be more convenient to do a hardware switching solution.

Answer (score 3):

As I currently don't have enough rep to make a comment, I will attempt a complete answer.

First, you most likely do not need an analog demux, a digital would be good enough, since all the stuff is running off 5V.

Second, you could, if you wanted, look for a device such as a CPLD. This is a software programmable logic gate array, that has non-volatile memory. Not as complex as an FPGA in general though. This would make your device capable of programming a different device, *just using a software upgrade.* Simply wire it up to many pins in the socket. (Please don't stone me for revealing this option)

Third, a [74138](https://www.google.com/search?q=74138) device would probably satisfy your needs.

Comment: If your device is large enough (e.g. Arduino Mega) then just hook up all the pins on the socket and you can control everything with the host MCU.

Comment: Hey this sounds like a fantastic idea. I'm looking into the ATF750 family right now

Answer (score 1):

I am proposing a solution but this has to be discussed regarding the possible issues and need to be redesigned or modified.Datasheet of [IC CD4066](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf)(CMOS Quad analog switch) encourages us to use it as a digital switch(here before i have used CD4066 to design a digital volume control)[image]
[image]

But this switch cannot be used to apply power to the micro controllers

Comment: if you have any possible issues just comment here.we would discuss about it

Comment: okay so I've actually seen this IC before. it looks like I could cascade 2 to get the triple throw that I need, so it's effectively a dual - SP3T.  So it cannot switch Vcc or GND? That means I would have to use 2 for the signals and another solution for the Vcc and GND.

Comment: @krb686 you can use transistor/MOSFET/reed relay to give Vcc and GND